Azure Pipeline - How to execute .exe file via cmd
i have an API that i execute the .exe file (SelfHosted) in my server and to do so i must kill the process in the Task Manager and start it again.
I would like to do it via Azure Pipeline but I'm having troubles cause the process doesn't start but it seems everything is fine in Azure Pipeline.
Command executed:

I`ve tried:
1 - with this command the process kept running but the step in Azure Pipeline was endless
cd C:\PATH_TO_FOLDER
MY_FILE.exe

2 - with this command nothing happened
call start /b C:\PATH_TO_FOLDER\MY_FILE.exe

3 - with this command the process started but as soon as it starts it closes.
start cmd /c "C:\PATH_TO_FOLDER\MY_FILE.exe" 

These are my steps. Btw i use IIS deploy cause i didn't find how to get the zip from my artifact and unzip it inside the path where my API is running:
Azure Pipeline Release Steps:


I can reproduce the same issue when using the commands shared by you. To keep the .exe running after the Azure DevOps pipeline completes, you can create a scheduled task to start your .exe. Here's how you can do it:

Create a scheduled task
Use a PowerShell script to create a scheduled task that starts your .exe. The task can be configured to run under a specific user account and to start the application with the highest privileges. Run this script on your local machine.


$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\PATH_TO_FOLDER\MY_FILE.exe"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "yourlocaluser" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal -TaskName "StartApp" -Description "Starts the application at startup"


Start the Scheduled Task
Add a PowerShell task in your pipeline and start the task created locally via Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "StartApp".




In Azure Pipelines, after the tasks and the job get finished, by default, the system will clean the processes started within the job.
So, if you use a shell task (such as Bash, Command line, PowerShell, etc.) to run the 'start' command to start a .exe file, once the shell task is finished, the started process of the .exe file will be automatically cleaned.
To let the started processes be not cleaned after the tasks and job gets finished, you can set the pipeline variable "Process.Clean" with the value "false".
In classic release pipeline, when setting up the variable, you can select the scope of it:

If selecting 'Release' as the scope, this variable will be applied to all the stages and jobs within the current release pipeline.
If selecting a particular stage as the scope, the variable will be applied to the jobs only within the selected stage.



